# Odd-dim vs even-dim vectors allocated in Julia

Tags: memory-management, julia, vectorization

Why do not *odd* dimensions seem to allocate extra memory when initializing `Vector`s? Example:

```
julia> for N in 1:10 @time a = [k for k in 1:N] end
  0.000002 seconds (1 allocation: 64 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 112 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 112 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 128 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 128 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 144 bytes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code deciding on array allocation has several branches. You can see it [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/95a5ad896bc049fedd795818ace3ab3fa67fc4e2/src/array.c#L98). In general what you can see is byte-alignment of allocations, which is governed by two contestants defined [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/6443a468817cba670e545c09561c16f2c30f31b2/src/julia_internal.h#L417).

Now the code is more complicated than this but in your case for very small arrays alignment is 16 bytes, so since `Int64` has 8 bytes every two consecutive sizes will have the same allocated size.

To read more about memory alignment see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

We can check that if e.g. you allocate `Int32` vector instead of `Int64` vector every four values get the same allocation. Similarly for `Int16` every eight values have the same allocation:

```
julia> for N in 1:12 @time a = Int32[k for k in 1:N] end
  0.000004 seconds (1 allocation: 64 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 64 bytes)
  0.000001 seconds (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  0.000001 seconds (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  0.000001 seconds (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
  0.000001 seconds (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 112 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 112 bytes)

julia> for N in 1:20 @time a = Int16[k for k in 1:N] end
  0.000003 seconds (1 allocation: 64 bytes)
  0.000001 seconds (1 allocation: 64 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 64 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 64 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 64 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 64 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 64 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 64 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 80 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
  0.000001 seconds (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
  0.000000 seconds (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
```

(remember that this is for small arrays, for lager arrays Julia uses different alignment, growing up to 64 bytes)