# PRNG allocation in Julia

Tags: random, memory-management, julia

Why is there extra allocation when a PRNG is given a `seed`, and how to "predict" the extra allocated memory? Example:

```
julia> @time a = Xoshiro()
  0.000018 seconds (1 allocation: 48 bytes)
Xoshiro(0xd53e541e5a9e5ee2, 0xa3e78308cafca7d8, 0x0e01f41edd308fda, 0x40f1d70265fa1fe0)

julia> @time a = Xoshiro(1234)
  0.000009 seconds (7 allocations: 512 bytes)
Xoshiro(0x9951797c85a704f1, 0xb9d66be14dfba82b, 0xb170153285fd9556, 0xe90a07f7bdd1fd77)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the `Xoshiro()` case the seed is taken from `RandomDevice()` as you can see [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/95a5ad896bc049fedd795818ace3ab3fa67fc4e2/stdlib/Random/src/Xoshiro.jl#L143)
and in the `Xoshiro(1234)` case the called function is [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/95a5ad896bc049fedd795818ace3ab3fa67fc4e2/stdlib/Random/src/Xoshiro.jl#L156). Internally it uses the `make_seed` function which allocates an extra vector of `UInt32`, as can be checked [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/99225ab1d11925b8e904b0b12f1ee8b0f6946660/stdlib/Random/src/RNGs.jl#L293). This extra vector causes additional allocations.

In general, a good thing about Julia is that you can check every question like this or your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73923257/odd-dim-vs-even-dim-vectors-allocated-in-julia) by inspecting source code since it is open-sourced and easily accessible. You can use e.g. `@which` macro for this. In our example the starting point is:

```
julia> @which Xoshiro()
Xoshiro() in Random at ~\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Random\src\Xoshiro.jl:53
```

which tells you to go to line 53 in `Random\src\Xoshiro.jl`. If your editor is properly configured you can use the `@edit` macro to go directly to this line in your editor.

Comment: Thanks! Will explore more source code then.